# Problems with facebook api posting to company page using application id: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am stuck with access rights in trying to post on facebook company page.

I have created an application and gotten appId and secret.
I have linked the application to the existing facebook page.
I have retrieved an accessToken for the appId.

But get the response: "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action."
Which user does the error statement refer to? the AppId user? The administrators of the page (me)? And where can I grant these missing rights?

I am trying to achieve that the post functionality is not facebook-user-dependent, but is company (or appID) dependent.

I am really confused about this...

Off course we could create a bogus user (kept in the company files) and post as this user - but that goes against the Facebook policy, and that is not the road we want to go down...

```
function FB_doPost(link, message, accessToken) {
console.info('doPost');
FB.api('/pageid/feed', 'post', {
    access_token: accessToken,
    message: message,
    link: link
}, function (response) { if (!response || response.error) { console.info('error occured: ' + response.error.message) } else { console.info(' post id: ' + response.id) }; }
);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to post to a Page "as Page", you need to do the following:

- Authorize a Page Admin with `publish_pages` and `manage_pages`
- Use the `/me/accounts` endpoint to get a Page Token for that Page
- Use that Page Token with the `/pageid/feed` endpoint to post as Page

Make sure you know about the difference between Access Tokens, here are some links about that:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: can the Page Admin be the AppId? <br>a code example?

Comment: everything you need is in the facebook docs, including code examples for the most important languages. you should start here if you want to use the js sdk: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3

Comment: this would also be interesting for you, i guess - it explains the login process in detail: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: i´ve also added some links about access tokens, it´s very important to know the difference and why you need a page token

Comment: the last link seems to use a facebook user - I want it to be user independent (just using the AppId)

Comment: It may well all be in the facebook documentation, but that is not really that easy to get to grips with - I keep getting sidetracked in the docs (ending up in deprecated sections and links to nonexisting pages :-(

Comment: I have understood the different access tokens and I am using an Application Access Token, but the problem seems to be to grant the correct right to the AppId on the page...

Comment: You need a Page Access Token, not an App Access Token. As @luschn said.

Comment: so I hadn't understood the tokens correctly after all .. sigh... so what I want is impossible? or can I use the app-access-token instead of the mentioned user-access-token to get the page-access-token?

Comment: But the description of the App-Access token says: " App access tokens can also be used to publish content to Facebook on behalf of a person who has granted an open graph publishing permission to your application."

Comment: you can´t just use an app token, app tokens have no relation to a page. follow the steps from my answer and use a page token. and of course you only get a page token by using the user token of a page admin.